# C# Oledb 0x80040E14 INSERT INTO error

Tags: c#, insert, oledb

I'm working on a project where you can add users to a database with the INSERT INTO command and an Acces database (OleDB).

I'm having an `0x80040E14` error which I can't seem to get solved.
Code below:

```
public void AddUser()
{
    OleDbConnection DATABASE_CONNECTION = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING);

    try
    {
        DATABASE_CONNECTION.Open();
        String SQL_QUERY = "INSERT INTO Users(Username, Password, Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam, Email, VolledigeNaam) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        OleDbCommand COMMAND = new OleDbCommand(SQL_QUERY, DATABASE_CONNECTION);

        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", OleDbType.Char).Value = Username;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", OleDbType.Char).Value = Password;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Voornaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = Voornaam;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Tussenvoegsel", OleDbType.Char).Value = Tussenvoegsel;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Achternaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = Achternaam;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", OleDbType.Char).Value = Email;
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("VolledigeNaam", OleDbType.Char).Value = VolledigeNaam;

        int rows = COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DATABASE_CONNECTION.Close();

        if (rows > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAIL");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Password is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in MSAccess. To use it you need to enclose it in square brackets

```
   String SQL_QUERY = "INSERT INTO Users(Username, [Password], Voornaam, Tussenvoegsel, " + 
                      "Achternaam, Email, VolledigeNaam) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

However, if it is still possible, change the column name because this problem will be very annoying.

There is another error in your code.

The method [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires, as second parameter, the value for of the `OleDbParameter`, not the type.

```
  COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", Username);
  ....
```

Comment: I was not aware of this, thank you so much for helping me solving this problem!