# C# - oledb exception syntax error (0x80040E14) in insert into statement

Tags: c#, oledb

Hi I've got a problem: My OleDbCommand not working.

Element of code:

```
    private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Account (Nick,Password) values ('" + NickEnter.Text + "', '" + PassEnter.Text + "');";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error! | " + ex, "Error!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and When you say not working, what is happening ?

Comment: Use parameters instead of concatenating the string. It's a security issue.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".  What steps do you take, and what happens?  What errors do you get or what unexpected events happen?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp)

Comment: 1. I readed it but i don't understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911465/oledb-exception-syntax-error-in-insert-into-statement-0x80040e14-in-c-sharp
2. how to do it?
3. error is in the title

Comment: Password  is a reserved word in several SQL databases.

Comment: I googled the error code.  First result:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905399/c-sharp-oledb-0x80040e14-insert-into-error  --  Your field name is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using reserved words for column names. You need to escape these using square brackets.
- Also you should use parameters for your values. This guards against sql injection (where possible) and also ensures that a value with a single quote does not destroy the statement.
- Finally I noticed you have a field named `password` and a plain text value, you should never store passwords as plain text. Instead store a 1 way hash of the password. There are many libraries out there you can use.

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Account] ([Nick],[Password]) values (?,?);";

        // note that order is critical here
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@nick", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = NickEnter.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@password", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = PassEnter.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error! | " + ex, "Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very mutch! I cant give u +1 with no 15 reputation :[